# How to debug the new Symfony 4.4 local server with PhpStorm?

Tags: php, symfony, phpstorm

With Symfony 4.4, after having install the `symfony` command, I run:

`symfony server:run`

and I get these informations:

[image: Symfony is launching]

Then the website works and I have Xdebug setup:

[image: xdebug available]

I can see directly `php_info()` and it gives

[image: php infos]

where `topt` is my username

Now how can I debug this on PhpStorm/Idea? I tried to listen for PHP Debug Connections and installed a Firefox Xdebug extension. Last time, it was not that difficult to setup.

#### EDIT

After more tests, I have a strong contradiction between my php.ini and the result sent by the Phpstorm validation script. I put the port as 11000, but it's still read as 9000. I tripled check the `php.ini` file location.

[image: Validation result]
In the same idea, if I uncomment `zend_extension` key, the symfoy server will warn that xdebug is alredy loaded.

So something teels me I have a double conf, and one is replacing the other.

However I don't see anything suspicious here:
[image: list of php Ini files]

Comment: *"Now how can I debug this on PhpStorm/Idea?"* Same way as before: configure Xdebug, pass "debug me" flag with request and debug. You will be debugging the web page, so the Xdebug browser extension will work the same. https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/documentation/debugging/ and https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/debugging-with-phpstorm-ultimate-guide.html

Comment: 1) You need to post your `phpinfo()` output captured via browser (you are trying to debug a web page, right?). Sections needed: the very top one with PHP general info (will show what config files are used) and the actual Xdebug section (will tell the actual live values). 2) You may still be editing the WRONG config file. For example: you are putting your stuff in a master php.ini .. but Xdebug specific settings can be stored (and therefore edited) in Xdebug specific included .ini file (just as your screenshot shows)

Comment: "Can't load XDebug it was already loaded" often occurs when installing xdebug or composer by **apt-get** instead of  **[official way](https://getcomposer.org/download/)** and **pecl**.